# Confusion regarding change of bases related problems.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> In $\mathbb{R}^3,$ let $\alpha_1=(1,0,1),\alpha_2=(0,1,-2),\alpha_3=(-1,-1,0),$ If $f$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$f(\alpha_1)=1,\hspace{1cm}f(\alpha_2)=-1,\hspace{1cm}f(\alpha_3)=3,$$ and if $\alpha=(a,b,c),$ find $f(\alpha).$

I have a slight confusion regarding the concepts related to change of bases. So if write down the matrix of transformation $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3\end{bmatrix}$ and then apply it to $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix},$ I would get $f(\alpha)=a-b+3c.$

But something seems to be off here in what I'm doing. If I am applying the transformation shouldn't $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ be represented with the coordinate matrix with respect to the basis $\mathscr B=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}.$

If so then the coordinates shall be $\begin{bmatrix}2a-2b-c\\a-b-c\\a-2b-c\end{bmatrix}$ so that after applying the transformation $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2a-2b-c\\a-b-c\\a-2b-c\end{bmatrix}$ we get $f(\alpha)=4a-7b-3c.$

I think this second way is the way to do it. I have been doing many problems the first way and now it's high time that I sought this out. So, **Am I Right?, If not what is the right way?**

Comment: Are you right? If $f(a,b,c)=a-b$ then $f(\alpha_3)=f(-1,-1,0)=0\ne3$. I think you are not right.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thanks! What is the right way tho : P

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I had the coordinates wrong before. Now it seems right.

Comment: Are you right? If $f(a,b,c)=-2a+5b+3c$ then $f(\alpha_3)=f(-1,-1,0)=-3\ne3$, I think you are not right.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown My computations where wrong all the time. I think the final edit must be right.

Comment: It checks OK?$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a question of solving linear equations: $\alpha$
has the form
$$(a,b,c)\mapsto xa+yb+zc$$
for some $x$, $y$, $z$. So all you have to do is to find the unknowns
so that it works for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$. This means solving
simultaneous equations:
\begin{align}
x+z&=1\\
y-2z&=-1\\
-x-y&=3.
\end{align}

Comment: happy 20000 twenty

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let

$e_1=(1,0,0);$

$e_2=(0,1,0);$

$e_3=(0,0,1) $

then

$$f (\alpha_1)=f (e_1)+f (e_3)= 1$$
$$f (\alpha_2)=f (e_2)-2f (e_3)=-1$$
$$f (\alpha_3)=-f (e_1)-f (e_2)=3$$

solve this system to find $f (e_1),f (e_2),f (e_3) $

then you get
$$f (\alpha)=af (e_1)+bf (e_2)+cf (e_3) $$
$$=-7a+4b-3c $$